# Post to MongoDB Data API: postman or curl work fine, fetch does not - wrong code for fetch (beginner...)?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, curl, fetch-api

I want to add a record to a MongoDB collection with the new MongoDB Data API. It works perfectly with Postman or curl with this code:

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://data.mongodb-api.com/app/<Data API App ID>/endpoint/data/beta/action/insertOne' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Access-Control-Request-Headers: *' \
--header 'api-key: <Data API Key>' \
--data-raw '{
      "dataSource": "<cluster name>",
      "database": "<database name>",
      "collection": "<collection name>",
      "document": {
            "firstname": "John",
            "lastname": "Doe",
            "email": "john@doe.com"
          }
    }'
```

but fails when I use fetch:

```
function addUser(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    fetch('https://data.mongodb-api.com/app/<Data API App ID>/endpoint/data/beta/action/insertOne', {
      method:'POST',
      mode: 'no-cors',
      headers: {
        'Content-type':'application/json',
        'Access-Control-Request-Headers': '*',
        'api-key': '<Data API Key>',
      },
      body: 
      {
        "dataSource": "<cluster name>",
        "database": "<database name>",
        "collection": "<collection name>",
        "document": 
          {
            "firstname": "John",
            "lastname": "Doe",
            "email": "john@doe.com"
          }
      }
      
    })
    res.render('homepage')
  }
```

Error in MongoDB log: Error:

> "no authentication methods were specified"

Where is the error in my code?

I am a beginner with fetch to MongoDB Data API.

Comment: Maybe `Content-(t)ype` (with lowercase `t`) is the reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved! Had to add this on top of my routes:

```
router.use(express.json());
```

Hope this might help for someone else too :)